# PHP + MYSQL optimize complex query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, calculation

Dear Stackoverflow members,

**My problem**

I need help with the following in MYSQL:
For a website that rents accommodations I need to calculate the availability of the rooms.

A scenario:
A user wants to book an accommodation for 8 persons on 21.10.2018 and for a duration of 7 nights.
The system then needs to find all accommodations that have rooms available everyday for 8 persons for the duration of the stay. This can be any combination of rooms.

**My table structures (only the necessary columns):**

item (table with accommodations):
id

availability:
id|fkItemRoom|arrival_date|arrival_possible|departure_possible|allotment

item_room:
id|fkItemId|fkRoomId

room:
id|max_occupancy

Each row in the availability table is a date with an itemroom that indicates if it has allotment on that day. So to calculate availability for 7 nights, A room needs to have 7 rows in the Availability table that have allotment for that itemroom on all 7 days consectuive.

**My current solution:**

This solution returns all accommodations that are available, and with SUM I made a little approach to count the availability. I know it isn't the right way.

```
        $vars['allotment'] = 8;
        $vars['duration'] = $duration;
        $ids = array();
        $availableParts = array();
        $allotmentParts = array();
        $wParts = array();
        foreach($arrivalDates as $key => $date) {
            $durationDates = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < $duration; $i++) {
                $durationDates[] = strtotime(date('11:00 d-m-Y',strtotime("+ $i days",$date['from'])));
            }

            $arrivalDate = $date['from'];
            $departureDate = $date['till'];
            $availableParts[] = "(SELECT count(id) FROM availability ea WHERE ea.arrival_date IN(".implode(',',$durationDates).") AND ea.allotment > :allotment AND ea.fkItemRoom = ir.id)";
            $allotmentParts[] = "(SELECT SUM(ea.allotment * r.max_occupancy) FROM availability ea WHERE ea.arrival_date IN(".implode(',',$durationDates).") AND ea.allotment > 0 AND ea.fkItemRoom = ir.id)";
            $wParts[] = "(ir.id IN (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM availability ea WHERE ea.arrival_date = $arrivalDate AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                        ir.id IN (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM availability ea WHERE ea.arrival_date = $departureDate AND ea.departure_possible = 1))";
        }

        $query = " 
            SELECT
                ir.fkItemId,
                GREATEST(".implode(',', $availableParts).",-1) as total_available,
                GREATEST(".implode(',', $allotmentParts).",-1) as total_allotment
            FROM 
                item_room ir
            INNER JOIN
                room r
            ON 
                r.id = ir.fkRoomId
            WHERE 
                (".implode(' OR ', $wParts).") 
            GROUP BY
                ir.fkItemId 
            HAVING 
                total_available >= :duration AND total_allotment >= :allotment";
```

I need this solution to take in consideration scalability and performance.
If there is more information needed, please ask and I will provide.

The script is written in PHP 7.2 and MYSQL.

**If you don't know PHP:**

The php code generates multiple queries per period, from start date to end date. A user can opt to get results for +- 2 days. The main query then takes all these sub queries and puts them in the mysql "GREATEST" function with the php function "implode". At this point the query only needs to know if there is a period with enough available days and allotment.

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm not looking for someone to give me the perfect algorithm. I would like to learn and understand how to approach situations like this. Create a view, split it up in multiple queries, rethink my whole DB structure. This is just one real life situation out of many other complex ones.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate really isn't close to what this question is asking.

Comment: I have to agree here with Dirk @JayBlanchard .. so i vote opening this question again.

Comment: OK - there are several room booking algorithms available on Stack Overflow and I picked one. The question is a duplicate, it's been asked many times.

Comment: "The question is a duplicate, it's been asked many times." True about that one @JayBlanchard "MySQL available rooms"  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+available+rooms .. Geuss this search is more usefull for the topicstarter then the duplicated link.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've read all 7 pages of the url provided by Raymond Nijland, and none came close by. My problem is way more complicated, and the question is not asked so that someone will give me an booking algorithem, but to learn more about complex MYSQL. I want either to know if I made a bad database structure, or that I just can't fix this in one query. This is just one real life problem, which will help me figure out a lot of others. Would be nice if this question could be opened again.